# Passing Date Parameter to RedirectToAction RouteValues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, parameter-passing

When Passing a DateTime Parameter to RedirectToAction (Asp.Net MVC2) 
either by passing DateTime or by passing a date: "13/4/2000"

```
    return RedirectToAction("index", "ControllerName",  new { mydate =  DTHelper.PrintDate(myVM.someobject.someobjectDateTime) });
```

The parameter passed with this representation - which the controller can't resolve:

http://localhost:6105/ControllerName?mydate=19%2F6%2F2011

how can I make it pass as original (it works when I build the url myself):

(this will not work b/c %2F....)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try using the following format when passing dates around: `yyyy-MM-dd`:

```
var date = myVM.someobject.someobjectDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
return RedirectToAction("index", "ControllerName",  new { mydate = date });
```

Now inside Index you should be able to get the correct date:

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime mydate)
{
    ...
}
```

and if you wanted a time component use the following format: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Comment: Thanks, I will check it, but I might have some problems with EU/US format difference, But first I'll try this way.